# How to check if a value doesn't appear by chance with respect to a distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following *randomly* generated distribution:

```
set.seed(1)
mean=100; sd=15
x <- seq(-4,4,length=100)*sd + mean
hx <- dnorm(x,mean,sd)

plot(x, hx, type="l", lty=2, xlab="x value",
     ylab="Density", main="Some random distribution")
```

[image]

And a "non-random" value

```
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(-4,4,length=100)*10 + 100
ux <- dunif(x = x, min=10, max=100)
non_random_value <- ux[1]
non_random_value
# [1] 0.01111111
```

I'd like to have the statistic that show `non_random_value` is 
significant and doesn't come up by chance with respect to `hx`.
How can I do that in R?

Comment: @d.b Running your code give me `0.2913637` What does that mean? How can I tell that the `non_random_value`  is significantly different from `hx`? Can I get p-value also?

Comment: Not sure your code really does what you want it to. There is nothing random about it. Functions `dnorm` and `dunif` are merely giving you the value of the density function, not producing random samples. In other words, nothing would change if you set another seed. I'm guessing you want to do a hypothesis test, but the code in your question is a bit confusing at the moment.

Comment: This question is off-topic and really belongs to stats.stackexchange.com: it asks for a math explanation of what it means to be significantly different, and how to test it (IF I understood it right - it is quite ambiguous as it stands...). The bounty reason `Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.` confirms that the issue is not about programming.

Answer (score 7):

The function you want is pnorm(x, mean, sd).  It returns the proportion of values in the normal distribution, defined by mean and sd, that are less than x.

You can use pnorm in a two-tailed test to get the proportion of values that are more extreme than x (i.e. farther from the mean in *either* direction).

```
p <- 2*pnorm(x, mean, sd, lower.tail=x<mean)
```

Now interpret p to mean p% of potential values are farther away from the mean than x is.  Keep in mind that *any* value of x can come up by chance from a normal distribution.  You can't say that x is not random, merely that it seems unlikely to have come from the specified distribution.

Here's a [nice site](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/hypothesis-testing/two-tailed-test-population-mean-known-variance) describing this is more detail.

Comment: This does not appear to answer to the question because, using the method from the tutorial  with pnorm you are stating that  x the SAMPLE MEAN is not significantly different from the mean of the distribution, comparing it to with mNaught as its mean. The question wants to know if an OBSERVATION is likely to be 1.96 standard deviations (or 95%) away from the mean mNaught....those analyses are different. If the modifications to your equations above accomplish this, give some reasoning for the changes. Using your equation on the penguins, you get very different answers...can you explain why?

Comment: The basic theory is getting a probability from the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for a quantile.  The difference is that, in OPs case, the random sample is tested against a known distribution, whereas in the z-test the distribution is defined as that of the mean estimate and the quantile under test is the known mean.  The code provided works fine when you recognize that the SD of the mean distribution is the sample SD/N.
    > 2*pnorm(15.4,14.6,2.5/sqrt(35),lower.tail=F)
    [1] 0.05833852

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, Arcturus!